# Public void and returning an ArrayList in subclass

Tags: java, arraylist, subclass, void

I'm new to working with subclasses and such.
In Java, I'm trying to make a simple program, and I want to use a "public void" to print out 
an ArrayList in a subclass.

I have the main class "Person" and subclasses Convenor and Student. 
In the class Convenor I'm trying to print an ArrayList with students- course members and a string with
an announcement to the terminal.

What I have so far:

```
public class Convenor extends Person
{

private String kompetanse;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Student
 */
public Convenor(String name, String kompetanse)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    super(name);
    this.kompetanse = kompetanse;
}


public String getKompetanse()
{
    return kompetanse;
}


public void announce(ArrayList<Student> courseMembers, String announcement)
{
for (Person student : courseMembers) {
System.out.println(courseMembers);
}
System.out.println(announcement);
}
```

}

EDIT: (sorry it didn't get included in the original post)
I need help on the public void announce method. I'm not sure what to have inside it to make it work and perform the task I want it to (where I've started by using a for loop, but I genuinely don't know what to do there, at all) to make it print out the ArrayList and the announcement (string).

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: So what is the problem / question?

Comment: The mistake should be in this line`System.out.println(courseMembers);` . I think it should be `System.out.println(student.attribute);`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to replace:

```
for (Person student : courseMembers) {
    System.out.println(courseMembers);
}
```

with:

```
for (Person student : courseMembers) {
    System.out.println(student);
}
```

Otherwise, it will print the whole list multiple times.

Now you want to make sure that class Student (and/or class Person) overrides `toString()`, so that it prints something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(courseMembers);` will give you human-unreadable data, since `courseMembers` is an ArrayList of your class `Student`. You probably want to access an attribute of each `courseMember`, like e.g. `System.out.println(student.getName())` if you work with getters.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what you mean but check out this...

replace
`System.out.println(courseMembers);`

by something simimlar like
        `System.out.println(student.getName);`

that should print the names of every student of the courseMembers Array